# Django template "with" tag invoke an variable

Tags: python, django

There is a Django template, I want to use `instance.links[0]['href'].split(':')[1]` as a variable, and use a `with` tag to invoke it:

```
{% if instance %}
{% with "http:{{ instance.links[0]['href'].split(':')[1] }}/dashboard/speed?speed=" as url%}
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

And this is `instance`:

```
def set_network_speed(instance):

    template_name = 'project/instances/set_network_speed.html'
    context = {"instance": instance}
    return template.loader.render_to_string(template_name, context)
```

The above code is wrong. Could someone help me to fix it? Thanks a lot !

Comment: what is instance's class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for you is to add an empty args method on your instance object class.

```
class InstanceClass(AnyThing):
    def get_url(self):
        return "http://" + instance.links[0]['href'].split(':')[1] + "/dashboard/speed?speed="
```

Then you can use it in the template

```
{% if instance %}
{% with instance_url=instance.get_url %}
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
```

edit: Thanx for the comment Quentin Pradet. Fix can be implemented in the question too.

Even if it will certainly not conflict in templates, I would not use an existing command name as var name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Since Django 1.3, the syntax is {% with url=blah %}.

Answer (score 1):

No. Your can't do that in a template. Even if you did the rest of the syntax, you can't pass an argument to `split`.

You will need to write a custom template tag or filter.

Comment: Ok, Could you give me some advice ?

Comment: Yes: read the documentation on [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/).